# What is the best way to support different screen sizes in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, size, scale

I have a bitmap that I want to display on a canvas and I want its size (width and height) to be relative to the screen size, so if I have a big screen the bitmap will be big and if I have a small screen the bitmap will be small).

I have two options:

1. Create multiple versions of the bitmap, each one in different size, and put them in the appropriate drawable directory.
2. Use only one bitmap size and just dynamically scale it relatively to the canvas size and draw it as I want.

It seems that Google prefer the first way but I don't know why. Can someone tell me what is the preferred way?

Comment: Are you wants to Scale the Image related to Screen Size ?

Comment: yes. but i don't need code example, i only need to know what is the better way between the to options that i wrote, or if there any other option i would be glad to hear about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to Decode the Bitmap :

Where imagefilepath is the path name of image,it will be in String covert that to File by using

File photos= new File(imageFilePath);

Where photo is the File name of the Image,Now you set your height and width according t your requirements.

```
Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(photo);
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,150, 150, true);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);              
        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(true){
            if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                break;
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale++;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answere.but my question is more from the "best practice" point of view, i know how to implement the scale. i just don't understand why it seems like google want me to use different fixed bitmap sizes instead of dynamically scale the bitmap to the size i want.

Comment: it is good to use the single Image for Multiple Screens as Images are adjusted as per your development Screens.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know only the best out of the two options, then I'd say option 1. Option 2 will be trouble for small phones which cannot handle large bitmaps.